# What's the difference between "veggie" and "vegetable"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, register

What's the difference between "veggie" and "vegetable"?
Can I use them interchangeably? or is there any difference in terms of meaning and usage?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In **British English**, *veggie* means *vegetarian* (at least according to the [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/veggie)). It can also be an adjective which is used to talk about food that doesn't contain any meat or fish: *Going veggie can be tasty, easy and healthy too.* *Veg* is an informal British word which means a vegetable or vegetables: *I like both fruit and veg.*

In **American English** *veggie* means *vegetable* first of all. But of course it is more **informal** than *vegetable*: *...well-balanced meals of fresh fruit and veggies, chicken, fish, pasta, and no red meat.*

So, if you want to use *veggie* right, mind the regional differences and and the level of formality appropriate to your situation.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this differentiation. Yes, veggie can be used to refer to a vegetarian or vegetarian diet, but I think it is just as equally likely in British English to refer to vegetables themselves, with the context making it obvious which one is meant. i.e. "eat your veggies" would be a pretty common usage and nobody would think you were asking them to eat a vegetarian...

Comment: As British vegetarian I would second that use of the term in BrE could either mean vegetarian or vegetable, depending on context, and neither is a particularly unusual use of the word, but it is definitely informal (I admit I personally hate the word "veggie" in either use - it sounds infantile to me).

Comment: Call me uneducated, but I thought that British informal for the _noun_ "vegetable" was "veg", while the _adjective_ was "veggie".

Comment: @MrLister I think you're right, for example we say "Meat and two veg"  ("veg" is a mass noun like "meat", pronounced "vedj"), meaning one portion of meat plus two portions of vegetables; and we say "veggie lasagna" to mean a lasagna containing veg and no meat. "Eat your veggies" would be understood (maybe someone would joke about eating a vegetarian...), but sounds to me like something an Australian would say, or maybe something adults would say to children to make the veg sound fun; more common in UK is "Eat your greens" or "Eat your veg". Answer looks right to me.

Comment: "Eat" your veg is what my mother used to say c. 1955.

Comment: @SeanBurton In the UK, I have never heard "veggie" used as "vegetable", only as "vegetarian" - so, a "veggie burger" includes things like mushroom and/or nut based faux-meat products (e.g. Quorn, among others), and is a broader group of which a "vegetable burger" is a specific subset.  Important to keep in mind when reading menus!

Comment: @user568458, i also think "eat your veggies" sounds Australian to me, something heard on neighbours, or maybe because of veggimite.

Comment: The UK does have a lot more regional variation in dialect than outsiders seem to think, so it's possible that the word "veggie" meaning vegetable is more common in some areas than others. I'll concede that "veg" is probably a more common abbreviation for vegetable, though.

Comment: @Carcer Agreed, while veg is overall probably the most used term I can honestly say as a Scotsman I hear "veggies" a lot more. Us lot seem to have a knack for that though (tatties, jobbies, jakies being other common ones)

Comment: I'm American and anecdotally I can say _veggie_ is sometimes used as an adjective to describe people that are vegetarians. It tends to have a bit of a tongue-in-cheek element to it, and it's certainly less common than using it to describe foods.

Comment: "Meat and two veg" is a British slang expression for "penis and testicles".

Comment: "Veggie" is american slang for vegetarian as well, but I don't like it

Comment: I've also heard the word 'veggie' meaning someone on vegetable diet...

Comment: @user568458 Veggie lasagna is described as veggie because it is vegetarian, not because it is vegetables. Usually I would expect it to contain quorn or similar. If it was made primarily of vegetables, I would call it vegetable lasagna.

Answer (score 21):

Veggie is informal and casual and vegetable is standard English. You would use veggie in relaxed speech or writing and vegetable in more formal writing.

Comment: Note that *veggie* is also Standard English (just like *vegetable*). The difference is only in style, as you said – *veggie* is confined to informal style, with *vegetable* being fairly neutral.

Comment: I have noticed that 'veggie' appears in Australian media in situations where Brits use 'vegetable'.

Answer (score 3):

In Australian English, "veggie" is an informal way of saying "vegetable". In certain formal contexts, for example books about health or recipe books, "veggie" is frequently seen. However, in technical contexts (e.g. "is a tomato a fruit or vegetable?", "ginger is technically a vegetable") it is unusual to say "veggie".

Comment: Also, you'll almost never hear 'veg' from Australians.  Veggie is the noun: "Eat your veggies or you don't get ice-cream", and the adjective: "What is the even the point of a veggie lasagne?".  [Vegemite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegemite) gets its name from the fact it is a vegetable extract.  I would expect, though I don't know, that Australia would also be the only place you'd hear 'veggie' as a diminutive for persons suffering from [severe brain damage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_vegetative_state), that may be known (by the politically incorrect) as vegetables elsewhere.